# Google App analytics/Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, analytics

I have implemented firebase to my iPhone app, in Google analytics on my Macbook I can see the reports when I switch Property in Admin section. But I can't see the data on Google Analytics application, all I can see is "All mobile App Data", which is basically just Google data after implemented Google analytics tracking code, not Firebase tracking.

Is there any way to see Firebase analytics data on the iphone app or do I have to implement Google analytics tracking code as well?

Or is there better tool for app analytics?

Thank you for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase installed, you can either:

1. Use Firebase Reporting in GA, which just displays the Firebase Analytics interface in GA.
2. Install GTM on your app alongside Firebase and use GTM to fire off tags to GA when certain Firebase events are fired.

Firebase mobile integration and GA mobile intergration are separate things.